# Creating texlive package with installable dependencies

Tags: packages, texlive, tlmgr

For my first latex package (called dummy), i have a basic `TDS` structure ready and running. I want to install it with `tlmgr`.

```
dummy
│
└───tex
│   │
│   └───latex
│       │
│       └───dummy
│           │
│           │   dummy.sty
│   
└───tlpkg
    │
    └───tlpobj
        │   
        │   dummy.tlpobj
```

**dummy.tlpobj**:

```
name dummy
category Package
revision 1
shortdesc my first package
relocated 1
depend fontawesome5
runfiles size=1
 RELOC/tex/latex/dummy/dummy.sty
```

I'm packing it all up with:

```sh
cd dummy
tar -cJvf dummy.tar.xz .
```

Now i like to install my package including **all dependencies**, as there is a `fontawesome5` dependency defined in the `tlpobj` file.

```sh
tlmgr --usermode install --file dummy.tar.xz
```

However, this just installs the package `dummy`, and no dependencies.

---

**Uninstalling**
complains, that the found `fontawesome5` dependency is not installed:

> STRANGE: fontawesome5 not to be found in /Users/mg/Library/texmf at /usr/local/texlive/2022basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 1492.
> fontawesome5: package not present, cannot remove

What is missing here?

Comment: note tlpobj  files are part of the texlive ifnrastructure but I don't know any latex package that distributes one with the package. I have a few hundred packages on ctan and none do this

Comment: I have added another question as it seems to be a general problem with tlmgr installs. 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663447/tlmgr-install-package-with-dependencies