# tlmgr install package with dependencies

Tags: texlive, installing, tlmgr, dependencies

I am installing the `hyperref` package with the command

```sh
tlmgr --usermode install hyperref
```

The package has dependencies to a lot more packages:

```
depend stringenc
depend hycolor
depend bitset
depend ltxcmds
...
```

Ref: https://github.com/ravidosnjh/DoTeX-old/blob/51cc4a72652b77eadd14c6cc8ff057a5ae6463d5/texlive/2021/tlpkg/tlpobj/hyperref.tlpobj

Although the official `tlmgr` documentation states, that all dependencies get installed,
only hyperref gets actually installed:

> (By default, installing a package ensures that all dependencies of this package are fulfilled.)

https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#install-option...-pkg

---

When uninstalling, the `tlmgr --usermode uninstall hyperref` command complains, that these packages are not installed.

> STRANGE: hycolor not to be found in /Users/dd/Library/texmf at /usr/local/texlive/2022basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 1492.
> STRANGE: ltxcmds not to be found in /Users/dd/Library/texmf at /usr/local/texlive/2022basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 1492.
> ...

How can i set `tlmgr` to auto install all dependencies?

Note: Behaviour is exactly the same without `--usermode` flag.

Comment: `tlmgr --usermode` doesn't do anything useful for a texlive from tug as far as I understand, it's more of a hook for debian and similar distributions

Comment: `tlmgr --help` says `Before using "tlmgr" in user mode, you have to set up the user tree with   the "init-usertree" action.` (have you done this?)  I have been using tlmgr for some decades but have never used user-mode, what is your use case here?

Comment: yes, i have initiated the tree.
The behaviour is exactly the same without `--usermode`.

Comment: `--usermode` is very usefull as it would otherwise require `sudo` to install a latex package, which you should better avoid

Comment: @flymg If you give yourself permissions for `/usr/local/texlive` you can easily avoid any use of sudo during installation and/or updates

Comment: you only need sudo if you install under sudo, personally I do the initiall install in a directory not requiring sudo but as you say usermode is not the issue I'll delete comments